# OpenCV: Can't find large rectangle contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

Opencv vers: 4.5

I'm trying to re-create the dimensions of an object by setting it up on a grid and taking as close to a top-down photo I can which I will then get the contours of the largest bounding rectangle and then perspective warp.

I'm currently unable to get the contour for a large bounding square however, it continually only finds smaller rectangles/squares which I'm assuming would not be large enough to properly fix the perspective.

First image: Original

[image]

Second image: What I get with my code using openCV
[image]

Third image: Close to what I'd ideally get
[image]

My code:

```
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# load the query image
image = cv.imread("path/to/image")

# make image greyscale, blur, find edges
grayscale_image = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv.adaptiveThreshold(grayscale_image, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                              cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

# find contours in the threshed image, keep only the largest
# ones
cnts = cv.findContours(
    thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]

# draw contours for reference
cv.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Instead of adaptive thresholding for pre-processing I've tried using bilateral filter or gaussian blur into canny edge detection but the outcome still doesn't find large rectangles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm at a loss on why it can't detect larger squares. Also, if people think there's a better method for fixing the perspective so that I can accurately recreate the board dimensions please let me know.

Comment: There is no real need to draw a large rectangle, known grid points are enough o fit the perspective, even irregularly placed. I suggest that you decompose all contours in horizontal and vertical sections to find corners (drop the oblique sections). If you want, you may keep only those close to the image edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may apply the following stages:

- Apply threshold using `cv2.threshold` (instead of `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`).
- Apply opening with long column vector for keeping only the vertical lines.
- Find contours in `vert_lines`.
- Sort contours left to right.
- Draw most left and most right contours on a sketch (black) image.
- Apply opening with long row vector for keeping only the horizontal lines, find contours, sort top to bottom, and draw top and bottom contours.
- Find inner contours in the sketch image (with the left, right, top and bottom lines).
  The inner contour is the smallest one.

---

Here is a code sample:

```
import imutils
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the query image
image = cv2.imread("image.png")

# make image greyscale, blur, find edges
grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grayscale_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
thresh = cv2.threshold(grayscale_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Apply automatic threshold (use THRESH_OTSU).

rect_im = np.zeros_like(thresh)  # Sketch image

# Apply opening with long column vector for keeping only the vertical lines.
vert_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones(50))

# Apply opening with long row vector for keeping only the horizontal lines.
horz_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((1,50)))

# Find contours in vert_lines
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cv2.findContours(vert_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE))

# Sort contours left to right.
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda c: cv2.boundingRect(c)[0])  # cv2.boundingRect(c)[0] is the left side x coordinate.

cv2.drawContours(rect_im, [cnts[0], cnts[-1]], -1, 255, -1) # Draw left and right contours

# Find contours in horz_lines
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cv2.findContours(horz_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE))

# Sort contours top to bottom.
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda c: cv2.boundingRect(c)[1])  # cv2.boundingRect(c)[1] is the top y coordinate.

cv2.drawContours(rect_im, [cnts[0], cnts[-1]], -1, 255, -1)  # Draw top and bottom contours

# Find contours in rect_im
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cv2.findContours(rect_im, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE))  # Note: use RETR_TREE for getting inner contour.

c = min(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)  # Get the smallest contour

# Draw contour for reference
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

---

Results:

`thresh`:
[image]

`vert_lines`:
[image]

`horz_lines`:
[image]

Left and right lines:
[image]

`rect_im`:
[image]

`image` (output):
[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you for such a thorough breakdown.